# ajax repeats previous requests

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm working with codeigntier and i'm trying some stuff with `ajax`. This is somewhat difficult to explain.

I have a controller Products with a method "overview", and a view "products_overview".

[This is the controller](http://www.mc-bronneberg.com/products.txt)

[This is the view](http://www.mc-bronneberg.com/products_overview.txt)

My problem is, is when I make the ajax call in the view in this part:

```
$('body').delegate('#notification-close', 'click', function(){
    $('#notification').fadeOut(200, function(){
        $('#notification').remove();
    });

    $('#blanket').fadeOut(200).remove();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<?php echo $current_get_url; ?>',
        success : function (result) {
            $('#column-middle').html(result);
        }
    });

});
```

It doubles the ajax call everytime i use it. And something else. The products controller creates pagination links. When I go back and forth a few times, I also make ajax calls. Let's say I do that 4 times. Then, when I use the above ajax call, it will execute those 4 previous calls and then start doubling from that!

So, i'm kind of lost here. When I put a `setTimeout` on `$('#column-middle').html(result)`, it will execute once, but then give a `jQuery` error that "result" is not defined.

Comment: I would put `console.log()` calls pretty much everywhere so you have a decent trace of what is happening. Then you can find out what is initiating the extra ajax calls. Or use Chrome which can record a JS trace itself. (note - console.log doesn't work in many IE versions)

Comment: A delegate on the body? You could simply use `$('#notification-close').live('click', ...)`

Comment: You got to split the question in two.

Comment: What do u mean with split the question? What should I ask, maybe it will help?

Comment: So I did some console.log()-ing. It turned out that the ajax call was executed way before the notification was removed, thus leading to a repeating click event and so a repeating ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You should return `false` from a [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) handler function to stop event bubbling, e.g.:

```
$('body').delegate('#notification-close', 'click', function(){
    // processing

    // stop further handlers from executing
    return false;
});
```

See [caveats section here](http://api.jquery.com/live#caveats). You can also abuse closure scope properties to prevent call doubling:

```
var column_middle_working = false;
$('body').delegate('#notification-close', 'click', function(){
    if (column_middle_working) return;
    column_middle_working = true;
    // do what you do

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<?php echo $current_get_url; ?>',
        success : function (result) {
            $('#column-middle').html(result);
            column_middle_working = false;
        }
    });

});
```

But still recommend you finding a real reason of this behavior.

Comment: That doesnt solve it though. Also, "result" in the above examle IS the content from the view file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `undelegate('click')`?

```
$('body').undelegate('click').delegate('#notification-close', 'click', function(){
    $('#notification').fadeOut(200, function(){
        $('#notification').remove();
    });

    $('#blanket').fadeOut(200).remove();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<?php echo $current_get_url; ?>',
        success : function (result) {
            $('#column-middle').html(result);
        }
    });

});
```